# Geospatial rolling average from geohashes on BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, postgis, geohashing

Geohashes form a grid, much like a matrix.

If I have a table with a geohash7 and a value, how could I calculate say the average of all the adjacentcells on BigQuery?

Sample source table

| geohash7 | value |
| --- | --- |
| r1q6fh3 | 7 |
| r1q6fh6 | 2 |
| r1q6fh7 | 5 |
| r1q6fh1 | 7 |
| r1q6fh4 | 2 |
| r1q6fh5 | 6 |
| r1q6f5c | 4 |
| r1q6f5f | 2 |
| r1q6f5g | 7 |

Sample output table

| geohash7 | value |
| --- | --- |
| r1q6fh4 | 4.6 |
| ... | ... |

Ideally in a scalable way as I want to run this over a large landmass.

Comment: Could you clarify more on logic behind finding average of all the adjacent cells? Looking at your expected output, it's the average from r1q6fh3 to r1q6fh4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need a function that returns neighbors. It is probably easier to grab one of javascript geohash libraries and use it as UDF, rather than do bit fiddling in SQL.

Once you have a function that returns neighbors, say

`GeoHashNeibors(center STRING) RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>`

You can then join original table with the flattened list of neighbors and compute average. Something like

```
WITH with_neighbors AS (
  select geohash, value, neighbor
  from data d, unnest(GeoHashNeibors(d.geohash)) neighbor
),
joined AS (
  select t1.geohash, t1.value, t1.neighbor, t2.value as n_value
  from with_neighbors t1 left join data t2
  on t1.neighbor = t2.geohash
)
SELECT geohash, ANY_VALUE(value) value, AVG(n_value) AS avg_neighbor
FROM joined 
GROUP BY 1
```